# How to run a python file with github workflow?

Tags: python, github, yaml

I was exploring **github workflow**.
And i want to run a python file in github workflow on a push event.
my `.yml` code looks like this.

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by GitHub!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo " The ${{ github.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ github.workspace }}
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."

  sending-email:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: send email
        run: |
          python ./send_email.py
```

the problem is on the sending-email job.

i'm getting the following error.

```
Run python ./send_email.py
  python ./send_email.py
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
python: can't open file './send_email.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpcaN.png)

my working directorly is as follows.
[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpghg.png)

Comment: You haven't checked out any of your code into the second job.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: Well look at the `steps` you're doing in the `Explore-GitHub-Actions` job, and compare that to what you're doing in the `sending-email` job.

Comment: Thanx i have added the checkout and now the file running. i didn't knew that we have to add that checkout in every job.

Comment: you can answer this question if you want

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the checkout repo in my second job.
We need to add checkout repository code in our jobs.

```
- name: Check out repository code
     uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

after adding the checkout repo my python file was running.